# Equivalence of Traversal Verb + て and で of Means/Instrumentality

Tags: grammar, て-form, particle-で

Consider:

- XにYで行く

  - 学校に自転車**で**行く

    - "Go to school by bicycle" ("means/instrumentality" interpretation)
    - "Is* bicycle and go to school" (Questionable?) (Verb conjunctive interpretation)
- XにTraversal Verb-て行く

  - 学校に歩い**て**行く

    - "Go to school by walking" ("means/instrumentality" interpretation)
    - "Walk and go to school" (Verb conjunctive interpretation)

The leads me to ask:

- Does て-form implicitly contain the で of means?
- Or is the で of means a て-form of something *(the copula だ perhaps?)

There seems to be something common between て-form and で of means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, yes, `で` is just the `〜て` form of `だ`.  You could get into a whole discussion on this, but we can see the parallels between them.

#### Connecting

> - イ-adjective: 大きく**て**強い　→　Big and strong
> - ナ-adjective: きれい**で**頭がいい　→　Pretty and smart

#### Means/instrumentality

> - Verbs: 行っ**て**くる　→　Go and come back ("Come back by means of (first) going")
> - Nouns: お箸【はし】**で**食べる　→　Eat by using chopsticks

As I said, this is an overly-simplistic answer, but I don't have time right now to jump into all of it.

Comment: Good answer, but I think the choice of 行ってくる could be better, since it's possible to interpret as a "connecting" use. E.g. お箸を使って食べる or OPs 歩いて行く might be more illustrative.